# Can A Crashed Hard Disk Of A Laptop Be Converted To External HD?? Can I Recover Its Data?

Tags: crash, hard-drive

I am recently getting a blue screen on my laptop all of a sudden after it boots up...

After booting, windows starts and hangs up after a while, which is followed by a BLUE SCREEN prompting a probable hardware failure....
It some times gives an option to start in safe mode, command prompt or normally.
but even then, the same thing repeats aferb windows starts.

Is It A Hard Disk Crash??
If, so can I convert that HD into an external one, and use it as an external HD?
Is it also possible to get back whatever data I had in it?

Comment: Off topic. Try super user instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the correct connector to the disk and plug it in as an aditional drive (SATA, IDE) or external drive(USB) in another computer, it will be read as a normal external drive. You may need a drive conversion set to plug it in as USB (IDE, SATA -> USB)

You will be able to copy any file on it.

If the disk is damaged or any of the files in it, is damaged, you wont be able to copy it.